# certificatesInBundle doesn't append self signed certificates

Tags: ios, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, alamofire

Using the convenience method `ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle()` doesn't appear to work correctly in my case

```
// MARK: - Bundle Location

/**
    Returns all certificates within the given bundle with a `.cer` file extension.

    - parameter bundle: The bundle to search for all `.cer` files.

    - returns: All certificates within the given bundle.
*/
public static func certificatesInBundle(bundle: NSBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()) -> [SecCertificate] {
    var certificates: [SecCertificate] = []

    let paths = Set([".cer", ".CER", ".crt", ".CRT", ".der", ".DER"].map { fileExtension in
        bundle.pathsForResourcesOfType(fileExtension, inDirectory: nil)
    }.flatten())

    for path in paths {
        if let
            certificateData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path),   // <-- we get the data of the certificate in bundle 
            certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, certificateData)  // <-- The problem is here, the certificate is not set neither errors.
        {
            certificates.append(certificate)  // <-- this doesn't run
        }
    }

    return certificates
}
```

Probably has to do something with the format of the self-signed certificate. I used exactly the #tip 5 from this blog post. [Five Tips for Using Self Signed SSL Certificates with iOS](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2013/12/12/five-tips-for-using-self-signed-ssl-certificates-with-ios/)

The question is what is the limitations of the `SecCertificateCreateWithData` method and which certificate formats are acceptable? Even better where can I read more about this particular issue.

my code appears to be correct it's nothing special, probably one of the most used snippets :P

```
let defaultManager:Alamofire.Manager = {

    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "localhost": .PinCertificates(
            certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle(),
            validateCertificateChain: true,
            validateHost: true
        )
    ]

    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.Manager.defaultHTTPHeaders


    return Alamofire.Manager(
        configuration: configuration,
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
    )
}()
```

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason that SecCertificateCreateWithData would return nil, is that the file is in PEM not DER format.

As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecCertificateCreateWithData), data should contain

> A DER (Distinguished Encoding Rules) representation of an X.509
>   certificate

If your data begins with "-----BEGIN...", then it is the wrong format. PEM can be converted to DER (and vice versa) with OpenSSL - here is a handy reference  https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html.

Also, in case of a self-signed certificate (judging by "localhost"), the `validateCertificateChain` property should be false. Otherwise the request will fail with a "cancelled" NSError.

Additionally, starting from iOS9, App Transport Security settings should be set to allow arbitrary loads (in Info.plist). That is the only setting that will permit self-signed certificates to be evaluated by your app. Without it, the Alamofire trust policy mechanism will not get a chance to kick in.

Comment: I found what it is and I did it in iOS 9.0 without allowing arbitrary loads. it's actually the encoding. Apple expects only DER and it fails silently in any other encoding. DO NOT  allow arbitrary loads. You practically open the back door and you are not using the certificate if you do it that way. I'll come back with a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. Alamofire couldn't find my certificate, the ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle() method did not return anything.

The problem was that when dragging my certificate into my Xcode project I didn't select "Add to targets: MyProjectName".

[image]

Comment: You've got to be kidding me... Thank you, this was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you downloaded the certificate in der format and added correctly to your project.

after that define a static SessionManager as mentioned below

```
public static let sharedManager: SessionManager = {
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "subdomain.domain.com": .pinCertificates(
            certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
            validateCertificateChain: false,
            validateHost: true
        ),
        "insecure.expired-apis.com": .disableEvaluation
    ]


    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))

    return manager
}()
```

then you can call the above sharedManager:

```
YourHttpClassName.sharedManager.request(url, method: .get, headers: headers).response { response in

            print("Request: \(response.request)")
            print("Response: \(response.response)")
            print("Error: \(response.error)")

            debugPrint(response)


        }
```

it should work fine with your self-signed certificate.